# Pandas: drop duplicated rows with same "rounded" values without creating new columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to remove duplicated rows that values in column `B` and `C` after rounding them to 2 decimal places are equal

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"], "B":[1.2579,1.2586,1.7223,1], "C":[8.2579,8.2586,12.7223,14.0]})

   A       B        C
0  f1  1.2579   8.2579
1  f2  1.2586   8.2586
2  f3  1.7223  12.7223
3  f4  1.0000  14.0000
```

Here, row `0` and `1` have the same value after rounding. Instead of creating column `B_round` and `C_round` to drop duplicates like this

```
df['B_round'] = df['B'].values.round(2)
df['C_round'] = df['C'].values.round(2)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B_round', 'C_round'], keep='first')
```

which I have to remove columns again

```
df = df.drop(['B_round', 'C_round'], axis=1)
   A       B        C
0  f1  1.2579   8.2579
2  f3  1.7223  12.7223
3  f4  1.0000  14.0000
```

Because my real data is big. Is there a way to remove them without creating new set of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with inverting boolean mask by `~` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df[['B', 'C']].round(2).duplicated()]

print (df)
    A       B        C
0  f1  1.2579   8.2579
2  f3  1.7223  12.7223
3  f4  1.0000  14.0000
```

Another solution - multiple by `100` and convert values to `integer`s:

```
df = df[~df[['B', 'C']].mul(100).astype(int).duplicated()]
```

Comment: Interesting that `keep='first'` is not important for `.duplicated()` here. It works great. You are so quick.

Comment: @Jan - it is default value, it is not important also in `drop_duplicates`

Comment: That's true. Sry, I thought `'False'` was default. Thanks.